# Getting Readiness & Liveliness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 503 during starting of Varnish using Helm Chart Kubernetes”

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, varnish

I am trying to create a Helm chart for varnish to be deployed/run on Kubernetes cluster. While running the helm package which has varnish image from Docker community its throwing error

```
Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 503

Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 503
```

Have shared `values.yaml`, `deployment.yaml`, `varnish-config.yaml`, `varnish.vcl`.

Any solution approached would be welcomed....

**Values.yaml:**

```yaml
    # Default values for tt.
    # This is a YAML-formatted file.
    # Declare variables to be passed into your templates.

    replicaCount: 1


    #vcl 4.0;

    #import std;

    #backend default {
     # .host = "www.varnish-cache.org";
     # .port = "80";
     # .first_byte_timeout = 60s;
     # .connect_timeout = 300s;
    #}



    varnishBackendService: "www.varnish-cache.org"
    varnishBackendServicePort: "80"

    image:
      repository: varnish
      tag: 6.0.6
      pullPolicy: IfNotPresent

    nameOverride: ""
    fullnameOverride: ""

    service:
      type: ClusterIP
      port: 80



    #probes:
     # enabled: true

    ingress:
      enabled: false
      annotations: {}
        # kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
        # kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
      path: /
      hosts:
        - chart-example.local
      tls: []
      #  - secretName: chart-example-tls
      #    hosts:
      #      - chart-example.local

    resources:
      limits:
        memory: 128Mi
      requests:
        memory: 64Mi

    #resources: {}
      # We usually recommend not to specify default resources and to leave this as a conscious
      # choice for the user. This also increases chances charts run on environments with little
      # resources, such as Minikube. If you do want to specify resources, uncomment the following
      # lines, adjust them as necessary, and remove the curly braces after 'resources:'.
      # limits:
      #  cpu: 100m
      #  memory: 128Mi
      # requests:
      #  cpu: 100m
      #  memory: 128Mi

    nodeSelector: {}

    tolerations: []

    affinity: {}
```

**Deployment.yaml:**

```yaml
    apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: {{ include "varnish.fullname" . }}
      labels:
        app: {{ include "varnish.name" . }}
        chart: {{ include "varnish.chart" . }}
        release: {{ .Release.Name }}
        heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
    spec:
      replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: {{ include "varnish.name" . }}
          release: {{ .Release.Name }}
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: {{ include "varnish.name" . }}
            release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    #      annotations:
     #       sidecar.istio.io/rewriteAppHTTPProbers: "true"
        spec:
          volumes: 
            - name: varnish-config
              configMap:
                 name: {{ include "varnish.fullname" . }}-varnish-config
                 items:
                   - key: default.vcl
                     path: default.vcl
          containers:
            - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
              image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
              imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}    
              env:
              - name: VARNISH_VCL
                value: /etc/varnish/default.vcl
              volumeMounts: 
                - name: varnish-config
                  mountPath : /etc/varnish/
              ports:
                - name: http
                  containerPort: 80
                  protocol: TCP
                  targetPort: 80
              livenessProbe: 
                httpGet:
                  path: /healthcheck
                  port: http
                  port: 80
                failureThreshold: 3
                initialDelaySeconds: 45
                timeoutSeconds: 10
                periodSeconds: 20
              readinessProbe:
                httpGet:
                  path: /healthcheck
                  port: http
                  port: 80
                initialDelaySeconds: 10
                timeoutSeconds: 15
                periodSeconds: 5
              restartPolicy: "Always"
              resources:
    {{ toYaml .Values.resources | indent 12 }}
        {{- with .Values.nodeSelector }}
          nodeSelector:
    {{ toYaml . | indent 8 }}
        {{- end }}
        {{- with .Values.affinity }}
          affinity:
    {{ toYaml . | indent 8 }}
        {{- end }}
        {{- with .Values.tolerations }}
          tolerations:
    {{ toYaml . | indent 8 }}
        {{- end }}
```

**vanrnish-config.yaml:**

```yaml
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: ConfigMap
    metadata:
      name: {{ template "varnish.fullname" . }}-varnish-config
      labels:
        app: {{ template "varnish.fullname" . }}
        chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version }}"
        release: "{{ .Release.Name }}"
        heritage: "{{ .Release.Service }}"
    data:
      default.vcl: |-
    {{ $file := (.Files.Get "config/varnish.vcl") }}
    {{ tpl $file . | indent 4 }}
```

**varnish.vcl:**

```
    # VCL version 5.0 is not supported so it should be 4.0 or 4.1 even though actually used Varnish version is 6
    vcl 4.1;

    import std;
    # The minimal Varnish version is 5.0
    # For SSL offloading, pass the following header in your proxy server or load balancer: 'X-Forwarded-Proto: https'

    backend default {
      #.host = "{{ default "google.com" .Values.varnishBackendService }}";
      .host = "{{  .Values.varnishBackendService }}";
      .port = "{{  .Values.varnishBackendServicePort }}";
      #.port = "{{ default "80" .Values.varnishBackendServicePort }}";
      .first_byte_timeout = 60s;
      .connect_timeout = 300s ;
      .probe = {
            .url = "/";
            .timeout = 1s;
            .interval = 5s;
            .window = 5;
            .threshold = 3;
        }
    }



    backend server2 {
        .host = "74.125.24.105:80";
        .probe = {
            .url = "/";
            .timeout = 1s;
            .interval = 5s;
            .window = 5;
            .threshold = 3;
        }
    }

    import directors;

    sub vcl_init {
        new vdir = directors.round_robin();
        vdir.add_backend(default);
        vdir.add_backend(server2);
    }

    #sub vcl_recv {
     #   if (req.url ~ "/healthcheck"){
      #       error 200 "imok";
       #      set req.http.Connection = "close";
        # }
    #}
```

Comment: Have you tried to run this deployment without probes? Maybe there is some issue underlying inside the pod. Maybe this answer will be helpful as a reference: [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60623528/livenessprobe-is-failing-but-port-forward-is-working-on-the-same-port/60633705#60633705).

Comment: @DawidKruk Yea I did tried without Probe , it was failing as the vcl response was not properly done due to syntax error..

Answer (score 2):

The fact that Kubernetes returns an `HTTP 503` error for both the readiness & the liveliness probes means that there's probably something wrong with the connection to your backend.

Interestingly, that's besides the point. Those probes aren't there to perform an end-to-end test of your HTTP flow. The probes are only there to verify if the service they are monitoring is responding.

That's why you can just return a *synthetic* HTTP response when capturing requests that point to `/healthcheck`.

Here's the VCL code to do it:

```
sub vcl_recv {
  if(req.url == "/healthcheck") {
    return(synth(200,"OK"));
  }
}
```

That doesn't explain the fact why you're getting an `HTTP 503` error, but at least, the probes will work.

Comment: Thank you very much it really worked out , was trying with syntax issue . I have created a Helm Chart for varnish which is deployed on Kubernetes Cluster . My concern is as of now as it is running up which I can see through kubernetes Console pod logs , I wanted to check if my varnish is properly caching the data . Any solutions/approached are welcomed..

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about that. As long as Varnish is running, it will do what it needs to do. 

You can't make general assumptions about caching behavior either: you will always have cache misses or cache passes on some of your content.

In order to know for sure, you have to define for yourself with "properly caching" means. This could be unique to your use case.